# How do I write it in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am a beginner in android and also in kotlin.

can anyone tell me how to write the below code in Kotlin.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Instamojo.InstamojoPaymentCallback {
    ...
    
    @Override
    public void onInstamojoPaymentComplete(String orderID, String transactionID, String paymentID, String paymentStatus) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaymentCancelled() {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitiatePaymentFailure(String errorMessage) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

From the left-hand side Option menu, select Android Project and right-click on the source code file. Select the option “Convert Java File to Kotlin File”. One can also use the shortcut command “Ctrl+Alt+Shift+K” while the file is opened in Android Studio. [reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-java-code-to-kotlin-code-in-android-studio/)

Your Code :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Instamojo.InstamojoPaymentCallback {
   override fun onInstamojoPaymentComplete(
        orderID: String?,
        transactionID: String?,
        paymentID: String?,
        paymentStatus: String?
    ) {
       ...
    }

    override fun onPaymentCancelled() {
        ...
        
    }
    override fun onInitiatePaymentFailure(errorMessage: String?) {
        ...
        
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is helpful, please accept the answer, it will help others as well.

Comment: Can you please give me a direct answer. I dont want to convert my project to java then write this code and then again convert it to kotlin.

Comment: You don't need to convert the whole project into kotlin. But I still post answers for you. Please check it.

Comment: It is still a long process.
i only want to know that how do i write this
`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Instamojo.InstamojoPaymentCallback`

Comment: Please check the updated answer